# Using locale in URL and routes in Laravel 5

Tags: php, url, routes, laravel-5, multilingual

I am newbie in Laravel and I have some problems with multiply locale. I configured all things and it works fine. My problem is using locale in url. For example when I click the 'man' category link it gives me `http://localhost:8000/category/man`. But I want to use locale in all pages. When I use website in English it should be `http://localhost:8000/en/category/man`and when I use website in Russian it should be `http://localhost:8000/ru/category/man`. I want to apply this technique to all pages, all URLs to get appropriate content for all languages. How can I do it, please give me some examples if it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

You need use Route Prefixes method :

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{lang}'], function () {
    Route::get('category/{category}', function ($lang,$category)    {
       echo $lang . $category;
    });
});
```

Comment: Does it do all my job? Or I have to add some other codes? Btw what is lang in prefix? I do not use `lang` in anywhere.

Comment: Yes it does , lang will give you the language user is passing in url , you need to know what lang user want to see